# MySQL SELECT...Output goes where on user access remote connection

Tags: mysql, select, cmd, directory, output

I have user access on a remote computer which runs a MySQL Database

I am testing some theories out and when i do a

```
Select * from db.table INTO OUTPUT "output1.txt"
```

where does the file go?

I tried doing 
`DIR "output1.txt"` in the C:\  on CMD and got no results...
It seems a bit strange

Regards
Jordan

Comment: I looked into the DIR C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin on the remote pc in case it set a default there but no luck there.

Comment: Try to put full path: `Select * from db.table INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\directory\\output1.txt'` and here must by [`OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) not `OUTPUT`. This query creates text file on the computer which runs MySQL database.

Comment: Hi, I meant to type outfile in this post sorry,
When i type a DIR it says that it cannot create the file which points maybe towards permissions

Comment: Yes, MySQL server must have permission create and write file to this directory and user, which runs query, must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file